# GWT designer: is it only for desktop application?

Tags: gwt, gwt-designer

i don't understand if with GWT designer i can build web (html) application. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Windows builder PRO](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html) published and supported by google. Window Builder was a paid software until google bought it. Now window builder supports GWT, Ext GWT and smart gwt design. And I think it is very good to design GWT, GXT windows.

To Add window builder to eclipse;

> Eclipse 3.6 (Helios):
>   http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.6
>
> Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo):
>   http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.5
>
> Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede):
>   http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.4

[Source](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html)

Answer (score 0):

"Create rich internet applications with GWT Designer, a powerful set of Eclipse-based development tools that enables Java developers to quickly create Ajax web applications using the Google Web Toolkit (GWT)."

seems pretty self-explanatory

Comment: ok, but on youtube's video, i see the GWT Designer used to build something like desktop app. So i got confused!

Answer (score 0):

You can developer GWT web application either. Here is [simple tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/tutorials/loginmanager.html)

Just start with (Exlipse)

1.New->Web application project

2 Open any composite or entrypoint with WindowBuilder Editor. That's all